# Uploading Image swiftUI Http

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

How to upload image to server via http request SwiftUI?

```
let body: [String: String] = ["email": email, "password" : password]
```

How to solve problem with type of body?

Comment: This isn't really a SwiftUI problem. You can trigger the upload from SwiftUI, but the upload process is the same as with a UIKit app. Can you provide more information in your actual problem?  See [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).